# Using pycrypto PKCS#7 to create a signature

Tags: python, pkcs#7

I'm looking at the Apple docs for PassBook, and I need to:

- create a "PKCS #7 detached signature of the manifest file".

I'd ideally like to do this with Python and I'd ideally like to use pycrypto for the task, the trouble is, I can't find any example code on the web on how to do this, there's lots of code like this:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA

message = 'To be encrypted'
h = SHA.new(message)

key = RSA.importKey(open('pubkey.der').read())
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(message+h.digest())
```

but not knowing enough about the specifics of PKCS#7, I don't know what I need to do...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Since this is a couple of years old, did you ever find a solution to it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With a lot of help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33726421), I did it!

I know op probably moved past this, but this answer is nowhere in the internet, so here's the solution, for posterity's sake!

```
from OpenSSL import crypto

with open(cert) as cert_file:
    cert_buf = cert_file.read()

with open(key) as key_file:
    key_buf = key_file.read()

pkey = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key_buf)
signcert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert_buf)

bio_in = crypto._new_mem_buf(text.encode())
PKCS7_NOSIGS = 0x4  # defined in pkcs7.h
pkcs7 = crypto._lib.PKCS7_sign(signcert._x509, pkey._pkey, crypto._ffi.NULL, bio_in, PKCS7_NOSIGS)  # noqa
bio_out = crypto._new_mem_buf()
crypto._lib.i2d_PKCS7_bio(bio_out, pkcs7)
sigbytes = crypto._bio_to_string(bio_out)
```

Keep in mind, it uses some undocumented pyopenssl functions.

Comment: I'm trying to apply this solution but certificate is supposed to be in `.pem` format, and key in `.p12` format. Is this a different approach to this problem that does not require to use `.p12` file all together and operates on raw `.der` files or I don't understand something about this solution?

Comment: Both my key and certificate were in PEM format. You might be able to change the parameters to `load_certificate` or `load_privatekey` to for your needs. You can also convert them to this format if that's suitable for you.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me , I was trying to sign a string for NSDL,

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
import base64
try:
    p12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open("/DSCPFX.pfx", 'rb').read(), "XXXX")
    # print("p12 : ", p12)
    signcert = p12.get_certificate()
    pkey = p12.get_privatekey()

    text = "This is the text to be signed"
    bio_in = crypto._new_mem_buf(text.encode())
    PKCS7_NOSIGS = 0x4
    pkcs7 = crypto._lib.PKCS7_sign(signcert._x509, pkey._pkey, crypto._ffi.NULL, bio_in, PKCS7_NOSIGS)
    bio_out = crypto._new_mem_buf()
    crypto._lib.i2d_PKCS7_bio(bio_out, pkcs7)

    sigbytes = crypto._bio_to_string(bio_out)

    signed_data = base64.b64encode(sigbytes)
    return SUCCESS, signed_data
except Exception as err:
    print("Exception happens in sign_data and error is: ", err)
    return 0, str(err)
```

Answer (score 1):

`cryptography` package (version 3.2+) can do this without using undocumented features:

https://cryptography.io/en/3.4.8/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization.html#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs7.PKCS7SignatureBuilder

Comment: Is there a corresponding function in `cryptography` to verify the generated signature?

Comment: @FrankLiu

1. Load the certificate
https://cryptography.io/en/37.0.4/x509/reference/?highlight=load_der_x509_certificate#loading-certificates
2. Extract the public key
https://cryptography.io/en/37.0.4/x509/reference/?highlight=load_der_x509_certificate#cryptography.x509.Certificate.public_key
3. Use the public key to verify the signature
https://cryptography.io/en/37.0.4/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPublicKey.verify

Note that you should also verify that you trust the signing certificate!

Comment: I have experience only with PKCS#7 (CMS) signatures.
You have to be aware of what is the actual data that is signed (raw data vs hashed, what hashing algorithm, what padding is used?).
There are many small details to get right, and a failed verification provides no information on how many of them you got right.

If you are also dealing with PKCS#7 (CMS) signatures, I recommend reading the relevant RFC - it's pretty accessible:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5652#section-5
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5652#section-5.4