# PKCS #7 detached signature with Python and PyOpenSSL

Tags: python, pkcs#7, pyopenssl

I need to get a detached PKCS #7 signature of some string in Python, using PyOpenSSL. I've got a key in .p12 file.

So far, I'm trying to do so:

```py
 from OpenSSL.crypto import load_pkcs12, sign

 pkcs12 = load_pkcs12(key_dat, key_pwd)
 algo = pkcs12.get_certificate().get_signature_algorithm()
 pkey = pkcs12.get_privatekey()
 sg = sign(pkey, manifest, algo)
```

But it's not what required.

I've searched net, but most examples are related to signing email chunks and use M2Crypto. Is there any way of doing it in bare PyOpenSSL?

Comment: In case its helpful to anyone it looks like they added a lot of this stuff in v 3.2 of https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#pkcs7

Answer (score 9):

The PKCS#7 OpenSSL functions that you need for this do not seem to be exported by the Python OpenSSL wrapper. You could try to do this via the internals of the crypto module, for example like the following snippet:

```
>>> with open('cleg.p12', 'r') as f:
...   p12data=f.read()
>>> p12=crypto.load_pkcs12(p12data,'passphrase')
>>> signcert=p12.get_certificate()
>>> pkey=p12.get_privatekey()
>>> bio_in=crypto._new_mem_buf(manifest)
>>> PKCS7_DETACHED=0x40
>>> pkcs7=crypto._lib.PKCS7_sign(signcert._x509, pkey._pkey, crypto._ffi.NULL, bio_in, PKCS7_DETACHED)
>>> bio_out=crypto._new_mem_buf()
>>> crypto._lib.i2d_PKCS7_bio(bio_out, pkcs7)
1
>>> sigbytes=crypto._bio_to_string(bio_out)
```

After this, `sigbytes` contains the signature, ASN.1 DER encoded. The constant value for `PKCS7_DETACHED` is defined in the `pkcs7.h` header file in OpenSSL.

As you probably know, any identifiers that start with `_` are internal to the `crypto` module and are not supposed to be used by you directly. Therefore, this answer is just for illustration purposes. A proper solution (with correct memory management) should be added to the `crypto` module itself.